# AngularJS - VM Data being set but not rendering

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following AngularJS controller, written in Typescript:

```
/// <reference path='../../definitions.d.ts' />

module baseApp.viewControls.products {
    export interface IProductsScope extends IAppScope {
        vm: {
            products: Array<common.models.IProduct>;
        }
    }

    export class ProductsController extends base.BaseController {
        public products: Array<common.models.IProduct>;
        public ProductRepository: common.repositories.ProductRepository = new common.repositories.ProductRepository();

        constructor(public $scope: IProductsScope, private $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {
            super();
            this.ProductRepository.all().then((products: Array<common.models.IProduct>) => {
                this.products = products;
                $scope.vm = this;
            });
        }
    }

    function setRouteState($stateProvider:ng.ui.IStateProvider) {
        var state: ng.ui.IState = {
            url: '/products',
            views: {
                mainContent: {
                    templateUrl: 'viewcontrols/products/products.html',
                    controller: 'ProductsController'
                }
            },
            cache: false
        };

        $stateProvider.state('app.products', state);
    }

    export var productsComponentModule:ng.IModule = angular.module('baseApp.viewControls.products', [
    ]);
    productsComponentModule.controller('ProductsController', ProductsController);
    productsComponentModule.config(setRouteState);
}
```

The important part of this is the `ProductsController` constructor. In that controller, I set `this.products` equal to an Array of objects, and I set `$scope.vm` to `this`. I'm expecting this to give me access in my view to `vm.products`. In my controller, `$scope.vm.products` looks good. This is my view code:

```
<li ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
        {{product.modelNumber}}
</li>
```

This gives me a blank screen, although `vm.products` looks good in my controller. Strangely enough, if I refresh the browser, it seems like 1 out of 10 times this code works. That leads me to believe that two-way data binding isn't working as I'm expecting, and there is some race condition where rendering takes longer 1 out of 10 times and `vm.products` is actually set prior to rendering.

What is off in my understanding of this that is keeping products from rendering every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is off in my understanding of this that is keeping products from rendering every time

Some things:

- The XHR might be hanging.
- You might be doing something outside the angular digest cycle. Try `$scope.$apply()`